# Blackberry 10 prevent device to go to sleep mode

Tags: blackberry-10, sleep-mode

Sorry, but I am new in blackberry 10 development basically I am a Android developer looking for an API in blackberry 10 which prevent my blackberry 10 application to go to sleep mode. I want my screen active forever.

In my application I am using socket communication using QTcpSocket which is not working ones device go to sleep mode.

Comment: You should not ask for recommendations about API / libraries here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++

```
#include <bb/cascades/Window>
#include <bb/cascades/ScreenIdleMode> 

//... 

Application::instance()->mainWindow()->setScreenIdleMode(bb::cascades::ScreenIdleMode::KeepAwake);
```

Or QML

```
Page {
    onCreationCompleted: {
        Application.mainWindow.screenIdleMode = ScreenIdleMode.KeepAwake
    }
}
```

I haven't played with `TCP` a lot, but I believe it is supposed to work even though the app is minimized, not in foreground or even with screen shutdown, make sure you have the `Run as Active Frame` permission checked in your `bar-descriptor.xml` file. Many of my apps use `UDP` and they work fine even if they aren't in foreground.

Comment: Thank you very much @Roger Leblanc. I could not believe that there would one line is more then enough.